Filtering with multiple criteria output by another filter formula
I am working on some year-end reporting and trying to figure out a rather thorny formula for a compiled version of monthly reports and am not finding answers elsewhere.
I have a dataset of referrals that are reported on monthly throughout the year, which among other things includes a unique client identifier, the service type, and the enrollment date. Each referral is reported on a single row for each month, so each client can have multiple rows per month as shown here.



Service Month
Client Identifier
Service Type
Enrollment Date




2310
1111111
Housing



2310
1111111
Public Transportation
10.11.2023


2311
1111111
Housing



2311
1111111
Public Transportation
10.11.2023


2312
1111111
Public Transportation
10.11.2023



I am trying to figure out how to return the count of services for which an individual never enrolled for the entire year.
So far, I have identified the below series of formulas to get what I am looking for.
=UNIQUE(FILTER(Dataset[Service Type], Dataset[Client Identifier]=A4))
**Which outputs the list of services the client was referred to.
=MIN(FILTER(Dataset[Enrollment Date], (Dataset[Client Identifier]=$A$4)*(Dataset[Service Type]=O13)))
**Where O13 is one of the cells output by the formula above.
=COUNTIF(P13:P22, 0)
**Where P13:P22 is where the above formula is output.
While I have returned a list of unique clients in a separate calculation page, I'd like to combine these three formulas, but have been unable to merge them due to the difference in output data set. Essentially the goal would be to have the second formula use the output of the first formula to determine what is included.
I appreciate any help!
EDIT: Added a screenshot of a small dataset 

I developed the solution for you:

=LET(
  a,FILTER(Dataset[Service Type],Dataset[Client Identifier]=F2),
  e,FILTER(Dataset[Enrollment Date],Dataset[Client Identifier]=F2),
  u,UNIQUE(a),
  HSTACK(
    u,
    MAP(u,LAMBDA(i,SUM(--(a=i))=SUM((a=i)*(e=""))))
  )
)

For the selected client identifier, the formula provides the list of service types assigned to the client during the year and the per type logical value which is TRUE if the client was not enrolled to this service type.
Update
To get "the output to be one cell and a count of the trues":
=LET(
  a,FILTER(Dataset[Service Type],Dataset[Client Identifier]=F2),
  e,FILTER(Dataset[Enrollment Date],Dataset[Client Identifier]=F2),
  u,UNIQUE(a),
  SUM(--MAP(u,LAMBDA(i,SUM(--(a=i))=SUM((a=i)*(e="")))))
)

Test


Another way to get count of services (along with the service names):
For the given ids

get the first referred month for the service type
get the last enrolled for the service type (adjust if needed)
Table[Report Month], ">=" & first_referred
include if (first_referred > 0) * (last_enrolled = 0)

=LET(
  services_not_enrolled, LAMBDA(id, LET(
    first_referred, MINIFS(Table[Report Month], Table[Identifier], id, Table[Service Type], Table[Service Type]),
    last_enrolled, MAXIFS(
      Table[Report Month],
      Table[Enrollment Date], "<>",
      Table[Identifier], id,
      Table[Service Type], Table[Service Type],
      Table[Report Month], ">=" & first_referred
    ),
    not_enrolled, UNIQUE(FILTER(Table[Service Type], (first_referred > 0) * (last_enrolled = 0))),
    IF(IFERROR(ROWS(not_enrolled) > 0, FALSE), "(" & ROWS(not_enrolled) & "): " & ARRAYTOTEXT(not_enrolled), ""))),
  TOCOL(MAP(A12:A13, services_not_enrolled), 1)
)



Thank you for your input, this seems like it would work, but I don't see how it references to a client id when the dataset has more than one individual. I'd like to refer to a non-static reference and carry the formula down the list. It seemed that would happen somewhere in the lambda function, but I couldn't figure out where.

Apologies, but I can't figure out how to translate this recommendation into the situation I have. I have a separate range of values (the output of a unique formula that is returning all of the clients we had over the year), and would like to reference either the full range or each individual cell with a client's identifier. However, in replacing all "Table1[Client Identifier]" values, I would be removing the reference to the main dataset, and also creating a mismatched array for the filter formulas.

Apologies for the long delay in response, it's a busy time of year. When I tried inputting the following, using a reference to a cell with an identifier, the lambda function is not liking it.
=let(client_ids, sort(unique(Table[Client Identifier])), services_not_enrolled, lambda(A5, Let(not_enrolled, unique(filter(Table[Service Type], countifs(Table[Client Identifier], A5, Table[Service Type], Table[Service Type], Table[Enrollment Date], ""))), if(iserror(not_enrolled), "", A5 & " (" & Rows(not_enrolled) & "): " & ARRAYTOTEXT(not_enrolled))), TOCOL(Map(client_ids, services_not_enrolled), 1))

I apologize for being dense, but I'm still missing something as this is not returning the desired result, I also tried changing the value of client_ids to be A2 to no avail:  =LET(client_ids, SORT(UNIQUE(Table[Client Identifier])), services_not_enrolled, LAMBDA(client_id, LET(not_enrolled, UNIQUE(FILTER(Table[Service Type], COUNTIFS(Table[Client Identifier], client_id, Table[Service Type], Table[Service Type], Table[Enrollment Date], ""))), IF(ISERROR(not_enrolled),"",client_id&" ("&ROWS(not_enrolled)&"):"&ARRAYTOTEXT(not_enrolled)))),TOCOL(MAP(A2, services_not_enrolled),1))

I've updated my original post to add a more representative sample which has multiple clients rather than my original sample which did not. Even when there is only one client, it does not function when there are more than 2 services (unless only one of them does not have an enrollment date) or when enrollment date is present in one month, but not in the following month. This is extremely common as enrollment is not guaranteed in the first month a referral is reported.

@nickamiller, thanks for proving more details and testing. Please check the update when you get a chance.

Much closer and thank you for your persistence! The last remaining issue is that it's returning all services that they did not enroll in, rather than just the ones they were referred to and did not enroll in. I should have included that situation in my revised sample. For reference, there are up to 31 unique services, of which we offer 13. For testing, you could add some additional dummy clients with some other sample services like housing, work tools, etc.

@nickamiller, it's easy to work with you :) Yes, I was able to catch it once I added dummy data as you suggested. Please check the update when you get a chance.
